# Recyclerview providing wrong position on onClick method

Tags: android, facebook, android-recyclerview

I am able to view all the items inside the app as required, but while using onClick method to share the app content on facebook, it shows the wrong items with respect to the item clicked. I am getting the image, heading and other related stuff but wrong adapter position is displayed. e.g. if i click the third position, it will display the result of 4rth item in recyclerview. Can anybody guide me through this what I am doing wrong here.

Below is my adapter code:

```
private LayoutInflater inflater;
Context context;
Uri uri;
String str_uri;
List<Data> dataArray;
private int lastPosition = -1;

public RecyclerViewAdapter(Context context) {
    //this.dataArray = dataArray;
    this.context = context;
    inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
}

public void setDataArray(List<Data> dataArray) {
    this.dataArray = dataArray;

}

@Override
public CustomViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    // View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.cardview, null);
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.cardview, parent, false);
    CustomViewHolder holder = new CustomViewHolder(view);
    return holder;
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(CustomViewHolder holder, int position) {
    Data current = dataArray.get(position);
    holder.textView1.setText(current.heading);
    holder.textView2.setText(current.date);
    holder.textView3.setText(current.brief);

    // Using picasso to fetch image as the user scrolls down ... No need to store
    // all the images during start up.

    uri = Uri.parse(current.getLImage());
    if (current.getLlImage() == null || current.getLlImage().equalsIgnoreCase("null")) {
        Picasso.with(this.context).cancelRequest(holder.image);
        holder.image.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        HomeActivity.setParameters(current.heading, current.date, current.brief, uri);
        setAnimation(holder.relativeLayout, position);

    } else {
        Picasso.with(context).load(uri).into(holder.image);
        HomeActivity.setParameters(current.heading, current.date, current.brief, uri);
        // Animation
        setAnimation(holder.relativeLayout, position);
    }

}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return dataArray.size();
}


public class CustomViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener {
    ImageView image, facebook_Sharing;
    RelativeLayout relativeLayout;
    TextView textView1, textView2, textView3;

    public CustomViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        textView1 = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.heading);
        textView2 = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.date);
        textView3 = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.brief);
        image = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.imageView);
        facebook_Sharing = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.facebook_Sharing);
        facebook_Sharing.setOnClickListener(this);
        relativeLayout = (RelativeLayout) itemView.findViewById(R.id.Relative);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

        Intent intent = new Intent(context.getApplicationContext(), HomeActivity.class);
        intent.putExtra("adapterPosition", getAdapterPosition());
        context.startActivity(intent);
    }
}


private void setAnimation(View viewToAnimate, int position) {
    // If the bound view wasn't previously displayed on screen, it's animated

    if (position > lastPosition || position < lastPosition) {

        Animation animation = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(context, android.R.anim.slide_in_left);
        viewToAnimate.startAnimation(animation);
        lastPosition = position;
    }

}
```

Below is the Facebook Activity code:

```
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize(getApplicationContext());
    setContentView(R.layout.home);
    share = (Button) findViewById(R.id.share);

    callbackManager = CallbackManager.Factory.create();
    facebookLogin = (LoginButton) findViewById(R.id.login_button);
    facebookLogin.registerCallback(callbackManager, callback);
    shareDialog = new ShareDialog(this);
    // login.setReadPermissions("public_profile email");

    share.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            ShareLinkContent content = new ShareLinkContent.Builder()
                    .setContentTitle(heading1)
                    .setContentDescription(brief1)
                    .setContentUrl(Uri.parse(String.valueOf(imageView1))).build();
            shareDialog.show(content);
        }
    });

}

public static void setParameters(String heading, String date, String brief, Uri imageView) {

    heading1 = heading;
    date1 = date;
    brief1 = brief;
    System.out.println("BBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBB is ::::::::: " + brief1);
    imageView1 = imageView;
}
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    callbackManager.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
}
```

Comment: try my code,set tag to your view with position.

Answer (score 1):

Try this code,I **set Tag** to your **facebook_Sharing** view and get position on onclik()

```
  private LayoutInflater inflater;
Context context;
Uri uri;
String str_uri;
List<Data> dataArray;
private int lastPosition = -1;

public RecyclerViewAdapter(Context context) {
    //this.dataArray = dataArray;
    this.context = context;
    inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
}

public void setDataArray(List<Data> dataArray) {
    this.dataArray = dataArray;

}

@Override
public CustomViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    // View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.cardview, null);
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.cardview, parent, false);
    CustomViewHolder holder = new CustomViewHolder(view);
    return holder;
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(CustomViewHolder holder, int position) {
    Data current = dataArray.get(position);
    holder.textView1.setText(current.heading);
    holder.textView2.setText(current.date);
    holder.textView3.setText(current.brief);
    holder.facebook_Sharing.setTag("" + position);
    // Using picasso to fetch image as the user scrolls down ... No need to store
    // all the images during start up.

    uri = Uri.parse(current.getLImage());
    if (current.getLlImage() == null || current.getLlImage().equalsIgnoreCase("null")) {
        Picasso.with(this.context).cancelRequest(holder.image);
        holder.image.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        HomeActivity.setParameters(current.heading, current.date, current.brief, uri);
        setAnimation(holder.relativeLayout, position);

    } else {
        Picasso.with(context).load(uri).into(holder.image);
        HomeActivity.setParameters(current.heading, current.date, current.brief, uri);
        // Animation
        setAnimation(holder.relativeLayout, position);
    }

}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return dataArray.size();
}


public class CustomViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener {
    ImageView image, facebook_Sharing;
    RelativeLayout relativeLayout;
    TextView textView1, textView2, textView3;

    public CustomViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        textView1 = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.heading);
        textView2 = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.date);
        textView3 = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.brief);
        image = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.imageView);
        facebook_Sharing = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.facebook_Sharing);
        facebook_Sharing.setOnClickListener(this);
        relativeLayout = (RelativeLayout) itemView.findViewById(R.id.Relative);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
         int pos = Integer.parseInt("" + v.getTag());
        Intent intent = new Intent(context.getApplicationContext(), HomeActivity.class);
        intent.putExtra("adapterPosition", pos);
        context.startActivity(intent);
    }
}


private void setAnimation(View viewToAnimate, int position) {
    // If the bound view wasn't previously displayed on screen, it's animated

    if (position > lastPosition || position < lastPosition) {

        Animation animation = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(context, android.R.anim.slide_in_left);
        viewToAnimate.startAnimation(animation);
        lastPosition = position;
    }

}
```

Comment: Nopes, it doesn't work, inserting the 2nd element now !

Comment: Perfect answer. Saved my day. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

In case, any one comes here for this particular problem, this solution might help him/her.

Making dataArray static and using its content directly inside the Share content module will correct this problem. In adapter class, dataArray should be declared as :

```
public static List<Data> dataArray;
```

And inside Facebook Activity onClick listener, dataArray should be accessed direcly like :

```
share.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            ShareLinkContent content = new ShareLinkContent.Builder()
                    .setContentTitle(JSONAsync.dataArray.get(adapterPosition).heading)
                    .setContentDescription(JSONAsync.dataArray.get(adapterPosition).brief)
                    .setImageUrl(Uri.parse(JSONAsync.dataArray.get(adapterPosition).getLImage()))
                    .setContentUrl(Uri.parse(String.valueOf(Uri.parse(JSONAsync.dataArray.get(adapterPosition).getNews())))).build();
            shareDialog.show(content);
        }
    });
```